# EOFException in dataflow job writing to Spanner

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-spanner

I have a fairly simple dataflow job that reads from BigQuery and writes to a Spanner instance.   All the reading has completed but for some reason it is consistently failing with an EOFException when starting the write to Spanner and it is in the class MutationGroupEncoder.  There are about 5.8M rows and 1.36GB of data that have been partitioned, but then after writing about 3500 it fails.

Exception trace below - none of our code is involved in the stack trace, it's all library code that is marshaling the output data around.  I haven't been able to find anyone else reporting a similar bug.  We are on version 2.5.0 of the Google Cloud Apache Beam SDK.

[image]

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.EOFException
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn$1.output(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:183)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner$1.outputWindowedValue(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:102)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.BatchGroupAlsoByWindowViaIteratorsFn.processElement(BatchGroupAlsoByWindowViaIteratorsFn.java:124)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.BatchGroupAlsoByWindowViaIteratorsFn.processElement(BatchGroupAlsoByWindowViaIteratorsFn.java:53)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:115)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:73)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:113)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:43)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:48)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:200)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:158)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:75)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.BatchDataflowWorker.executeWork(BatchDataflowWorker.java:391)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.BatchDataflowWorker.doWork(BatchDataflowWorker.java:360)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.BatchDataflowWorker.getAndPerformWork(BatchDataflowWorker.java:288)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.doWork(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:134)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:114)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:101)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException.wrap(UserCodeException.java:36)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.spanner.SpannerIO$BatchFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:185)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:146)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:323)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:43)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:48)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn$1.output(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:181)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.spanner.MutationGroupEncoder.decode(MutationGroupEncoder.java:271)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.spanner.SpannerIO$BatchFn.processElement(SpannerIO.java:1030)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:197)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:169)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.spanner.MutationGroupEncoder.readBytes(MutationGroupEncoder.java:475)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.spanner.MutationGroupEncoder.decodePrimitive(MutationGroupEncoder.java:434)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.spanner.MutationGroupEncoder.decodeModification(MutationGroupEncoder.java:326)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.spanner.MutationGroupEncoder.decodeMutation(MutationGroupEncoder.java:280)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.spanner.MutationGroupEncoder.decode(MutationGroupEncoder.java:264)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.spanner.SpannerIO$BatchFn.processElement(SpannerIO.java:1030)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.spanner.SpannerIO$BatchFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:185)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:146)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:323)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:43)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:48)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn$1.output(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:181)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner$1.outputWindowedValue(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:102)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.BatchGroupAlsoByWindowViaIteratorsFn.processElement(BatchGroupAlsoByWindowViaIteratorsFn.java:124)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.BatchGroupAlsoByWindowViaIteratorsFn.processElement(BatchGroupAlsoByWindowViaIteratorsFn.java:53)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:115)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:73)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:113)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:43)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:48)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:200)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:158)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:75)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.BatchDataflowWorker.executeWork(BatchDataflowWorker.java:391)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.BatchDataflowWorker.doWork(BatchDataflowWorker.java:360)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.BatchDataflowWorker.getAndPerformWork(BatchDataflowWorker.java:288)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.doWork(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:134)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:114)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:101)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: I suspect it could happen because of https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/5722 could you try Beam 2.6.0-SNAPSHOT?

Answer (score 2):

had same issue and it's got resolved after changing to 2.6.0 , and was able to upload 100 GB (350 Million records). But i observed dataflow jobs are slow when compared with 2.4.0.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm this was fixed by PR5722 which was merged into 2.6.0 which was released officially 2018-08-08.